# How to retrieve custom setting using javascript remote object

Tags: javascript-remoting, customsetting, remote-access

In apex, normally we can consider retrieving info from a custom setting just like an object using query. But the simpler way remain the use of the getInstance method. But I want to use javascript remote object to get a paticular value from a field from my custom setting, how do i achieve this ?

This is a sample I came across for normal object :

```
   var wh = new SObjectModel.Warehouse();
   ct.retrieve({where: {FirstName: {eq: 'Marc' }}}, function() {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work.

In my page i have this :

```
    <apex:remoteObjects >
         <apex:remoteObjectModel name="CS_WebServiceDetail__c" jsShorthand="csSetting" fields="Name,Id" >  
         <apex:remoteObjectField name="PaginationCount__c" jsShorthand="count"/>
    </apex:remoteObjectModel>
</apex:remoteObjects>
```

where CS_WebServiceDetail__c is my custom setting and PaginationCount__c is the field i need on my custom setting.

Then in my script, I have this :

```
   var cs01 = new SObjectModel.csSetting();
    console.log('cs01',cs01);

    cs01.retrieve({where: {Name: {eq: 'setting01'}}}, function(err, records){           
        if(err) console.log('error while retrieving count per page',err.message);
        else {      
           console.log('retrieving the count for ',records);
           records.forEach(function(record) {
               count = record.get("count");
           });
        }
    });
```

In this example I am retrieving from my custom setting using the unique name.
Even if the name is unique the result will be an array of object.